# Android - Changing background every 5 seconds

Tags: android

I have this code in an attempt to have my app change it's background every 5 seconds, however, it only displays the first image in my array. Is there a simple tweak to this I can make so it will run through the 5 different images continuously??

Here is what I have in my MainActivity.class

```
    int count=0; //outside oncreate

    //all that is below is within oncreate
    final int[] drawablearray=new int[]{R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five};
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           if(count<drawablearray.length){
               MainActivity.this.getWindow().
               setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawablearray[count]);
               count++;
            }
           else{
              count=0;
            }
          }
      }, 5000);
```

Thanks for all and any help!!

Comment: Looks like adding a `new Handler().postDelayed(this, 5000);` after the setBackground call could work...?

Comment: Are you running this in a loop?

Comment: Yep, it was able to run through all of the images this way! However, it only ran through them once.. Any ideas on how to continuously run through them?

Answer (score 6):

You need to call the method recursivly. The way you have currently set it up you only call it once.

```
int count =0;
boolean abort;
onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    abort = false;
    this.changeBackground(count);
}
onPause(){
    abort = true;
    super.onPause();
}


private void changeBackground(int count){
    if (abort)
        return;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(count<drawablearray.length){
                count++;
            }
            else{
               count=0;
            }
            changeBackgroundColor(count);
            changeBackground(count);
        }
    }, 5000);
}

private void changeBackgroundColor(int count){
    if (abort)
        return;
    MainActivity.this.getWindow().
                setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawablearray[count]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'm sort of dealing with some silly errors though... Could you please tell me where I should be placing the different lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Spin in an infinite loop. Also, you can remove the if-else condition with `%`:

```
while (changeBackground == true)
{
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
           MainActivity.this.getWindow().
           setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawablearray[count]);
           count = (count + 1) % drawablearray.length;
  }, 5000);
}
```

PS: You may want to configure background change from some event, like on Event e, background changing should stop. One example of such event may be switching from one activity to other. You can achieve this by setting/resetting variable `changeBackground`.

Comment: Also ok, but make sure you have an abort to break the loop

Comment: Hmmm, would I put this inside my original if statement??

Comment: Which if you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
     //all that is below is within oncreate
    final int[] drawablearray=new int[]{R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five};
    gettingBackground(drawablearray);



}
private void gettingBackground(final int[] drawablearray) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               if(count<drawablearray.length){
                 LoginAct.this.getWindow().
                   setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawablearray[count]);
                   count++;
                   gettingBackground(drawablearray);
                }
               else{
                  count=0;
                }
              }
          }, 5000);
}
```